# htaccess, fake subdirectory to root

Tags: .htaccess

I would like this URL ->
http://www.example.com/games/Mario_Kart
to be redirected here ->
http://www.example.com/games.php?name=Mario_Kart 
I'm a total beginner and i tried this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^games/[A-Za-z0-9_-]{0,100}$ games.php?name=$1 [L]
```

It  worked but all the paths were broken (no css, ...)
And now, i don't know why but I have a 403 error.
I just want to know if my code is OK (I guess not)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^games/([A-Za-z0-9_-]{0,100}) /games.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Basically by addind () you can call it later with the $1, you were close to the result.